# Input parameter for Uri.TryCreate, what's wrong?

Tags: c#, .net, url, uri, relative-url

We have few downloaded HTML pages, with broken links (relative paths), and we have the original URL each page was downloaded from.

We are converting all relative links to Absolute links using -

```
Foreach (anchorElement in page) -
    Uri.TryCreate( originalPageURI, hrefRelativeURI, hrefAbsoluteURI )
```

This works for most of the cases except for the following case -

```
originalPageURI = http://somewebsite.com/post.jsp?item=22

hrefRelativeURI = ?item=97
```

What would be the input parameter for `Uri.TryCreate()` for above case where `TryCreate()` fails ?

Comment: There are 3 different overloads of Uri.TryCreate(). ?item=97 is not part of a path, but it's a query string aprameter. It can't be used as a relative path!!

Comment: @JotaBe so we just use new Query string parameters in original URL, no need to use Uri.TryCreate() for such links ?

Comment: You have to make your question more clear? Why do you need to create a Uri? Where are you using it. Please, explain.

Comment: We have HTML pages with borken links (relative paths),and we have the original URL the page was downloaded from. Now we converting relative URLs -- > Absolute URLs.

Comment: Please, edit your question and add samples of what you have and what you want to get, and what you're trying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't solve your problem with Uri because `?item=97` is not a relative path but instead a query string.

So, what you have to do is construct your new URL joining the parts by hand.

You should use:

- `originalFolderPath`, as the portion of your original URL up to the last `'/'`. You can join the "true" relative paths to this one to get the absolute uri. (i.e. those not starting with `?`)
- `originalFilePath`, as the portion of your original URL up to the `'?'`. You can join the "false" relative paths to this portion. The false are those representing the query string parameters (i.e. those starting with `?`).